# Vmware Workstation 14 does not let me direct <SUPER> key to machine

Tags: gnome, vmware

I am using ubuntu 17.10 and **VMware Workstation 14**. I have a virtual machine running ubuntu 17.10 running standard gnome3 on both.

When I am in the virtual machine in isolated guest mode, I can not switch between workspaces anymore by using <kbd>STRG</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>. Instead it switches workspaces on the host system.

From **Workstation 12** I was used that all key combinations get directed to the vm guest system. Only when pressing the global vmware keykombination <kbd>STRG</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SUPER</kbd> the host is active i.e. 
<kbd>STRG</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SUPER</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> changed between machines.

gnome-boxes has a new window pop-up but it also does not work. 
[![boxes asks before locking shortcuts to the guest][1]][1]

Pressing <kbd>SUPER</kbd> seems to be the problem since it is not triggered on the guest. So the problem boils down to:

How can I press <kbd>SUPER</kbd> in a virtual guest on ubuntu 17.10?

Answer (score 4):

This is a [bug on wayland upstream](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1285770)

Changing to xorg is the only solution right now. To do this, select *Ubuntu on x.org* in the gdm3 login.

Wayland is (for security reasons) designed like this and prevents redirection of key events.

This also affects remote sessions using i.e. rdp or vnc.

Comment: Still a problem in Ubuntu 20.04 and 21.04, thanks for save my day. I almost thought I have to give up my virtual machines

Answer (score 3):

I came here looking for "kali disable super key" but I suppose this applies to other linux vmware/virtualbox guests too, so I hope this helps.

In my case the solution was to set "**overview shortcut**" in **tweaks** to **Right super** .

That way I can use my (left) "command" key in my mac for copy/paste etc in the guest VM.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Seems like a valid work-around.